# Select same node which containing same name

Tags: xslt

I implemented the logic for determining which records from the input will be used is based on whether the value for `<ChildItem Name>` is contained in the `<Company>/<Code>` text in input xml.

I means several `<ChildItem @Name>` equals to `<Company>/<Code>`. I should select only this kind of records.

Input:

```
<xml>
  <ChildItem Name="SYD.AX">
    <Fields>
      <Field DataType="Double" Name="TRDPRC_1">
        <Double>1.995</Double>
      </Field>
      <Field DataType="Double" Name="NETCHNG_1">
        <Double>0.095</Double>
      </Field>
      <Field DataType="Double" Name="BID">
        <Double>1.95</Double>
      </Field>
      <Field DataType="Double" Name="ASK">
        <Double>2.0</Double>
      </Field>
      <Field DataType="Int64" Name="ACVOL_1">
        <Int64>2064846</Int64>
      </Field>
    </Fields>
  <ChildItem Name="EDR.GH">
    <Fields>
      <Field DataType="Double" Name="TRDPRC_1">
        <Double>1.995</Double>
      </Field>
      <Field DataType="Double" Name="NETCHNG_1">
        <Double>0.095</Double>
      </Field>
      <Field DataType="Double" Name="BID">
        <Double>1.95</Double>
      </Field>
      <Field DataType="Double" Name="ASK">
        <Double>2.0</Double>
      </Field>
      <Field DataType="Int64" Name="ACVOL_1">
        <Int64>2064846</Int64>
      </Field>
    </Fields>
  </ChildItem>
  <ChildItem Name="MNS.JQ">
   ...
  </ChildItem>
  <ChildItem Name="UAV.NL">
   ...
  </ChildItem>
  <Companies>
    <Company>
      <Code>SYD</Code>
      <ShortName>Sydney Airport</ShortName>
    </Company>
  </Companies>
  <Companies>
    <Company>
      <Code>FFD</Code>
      <ShortName>Filk Fully Derf</ShortName>
    </Company>
  </Companies>
  <Companies>
    <Company>
      <Code>MNS</Code>
      <ShortName>Minnas Ninib Survay</ShortName>
    </Company>
  </Companies>
</mxl>
```

Output Should be:

```
<p type="ASX Listings"><t/>SYD<t/>Sydney Airport<t/>5.88<t/>5.9<t/>5.88<t/>&#x2013;<t/>9.5m</p>
<p type="ASX Listings"><t/>MNS<t/>Minnas Ninib Survay<t/>5.88<t/>5.9<t/>5.88<t/>&#x2013;<t/>9.5m</p>
```

Tried code

```
<xsl:template match="ChildItem">
    <xsl:variable name="childName" select="@Name"/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::Companies/Company/Code[substring-before($childName,'.')]">
        <p type="ASX Listings">
            <t/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($childName,'.')"/>
            <t/>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Companies/Company[Code eq substring-before($childName,'.')]/ShortName"/>
            <t/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Fields/Field[@DataType='Double'][@Name='BID']/Double"/>
            <t/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Fields/Field[@DataType='Double'][@Name='ASK']/Double"/>
            <t/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Fields/Field[@DataType='Double'][@Name='TRDPRC_1']/Double"/>
            <t/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Fields/Field[@DataType='Double'][@Name='NETCHNG_1']/Double"/>
            <t/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Fields/Field[@DataType='Int64'][@Name='ACVOL_1']/Double"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I tried in various ways and. I have mentioned one of m tried code. I am using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) for linking to the corresponding company - for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="company" match="Company" use="Code" />

<xsl:template match="xml">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ChildItem[key('company', substring-before(@Name, '.'))]"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ChildItem">
    <p type="ASX Listings">
        <t/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@Name,'.')"/>
        <t/>
        <!-- the rest of the template --> 
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```